# SQL query with "group by with cube" and NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table like:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| A    | 1    | foo  |
| A    | 1    | foo  |
| A    | 2    | foo  |
| B    | 1    | foo  |
| B    | 2    | foo  |
| B    | NULL | foo  |
| NULL | 1    | foo  |
+------+------+------+
```

I want to see numbers of `foo` grouped by `col1` and `col2`:

```
+-------+---+---+------+-------+
|       | A | B | NULL | TOTAL |
+-------+---+---+------+-------+
| 1     | 2 | 1 |    1 |     4 |
| 2     | 1 | 1 |    0 |     2 |
| NULL  | 0 | 1 |    0 |     1 |
| TOTAL | 3 | 3 |    1 |     7 |
+-------+---+---+------+-------+
```

I use a query like this:

```
select 
    col1,
    col2,
    count(col3)
from table
group by 
    col1,
    col2 
with cube
```

And I have 4 rows with `col1`, `col2` and `NULL` that say for `NULL/NULL`, `NULL/TOTAL`, `TOTAL/NULL`, `TOTAL/TOTAL` but the totals for sql has `NULL` value.

Is possible set a custom value different from `NULL` for the totals in the query?

Comment: Can you post the output of your query rather than trying to describe it?  I don't understand your description at all.

Comment: For this you need to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use some conditional aggregation for this as well as a subquery since you want to use the "null" as an actual value.

```
select 
  col2 = Isnull(col2, 'Total'), 
  A = sum(case when col1 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end),
  B = sum(case when col1 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end),
  NullVal = sum(case when col1 = 'Null' then 1 else 0 end),
  count(col1) Total
from
(
  select 
    col1 = Isnull(col1, 'Null'), 
    col2 = isnull(cast(col2 as varchar(5)), 'Null'),
    col3
  from yourtable
) d
group by col2
with cube;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45faae/30). This uses a CASE expression to get the totals for both the `A`, `B`, and `null` values in `Col1` and then uses the `CUBE` to rollup the totals. Giving the result:

```
|  COL2 | A | B | NULLVAL | TOTAL |
|-------|---|---|---------|-------|
|     1 | 2 | 1 |       1 |     4 |
|     2 | 1 | 1 |       0 |     2 |
|  Null | 0 | 1 |       0 |     1 |
| Total | 3 | 3 |       1 |     7 |
```